# Python プログラムを実行すると ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams' エラーが発生する

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

spyderで配列を読み込んで図として表示させるプログラムを表示させることが出来たので、次にマウスで拡大や色々な角度からみたかったのでAnacondaで開いたところ以下のようなエラーがでました。
とりあえずAnacondaをアップデートしたのですが、状況は変わりませんでした。このエラーはどういった種類のものになりますか？解決方法を教えてください。 
プログラムは必要であるならのちに追記します。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "3D.py", line 7, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\init.py", line 124, in <module>
from . import cbook
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\init.py", line 36, in <module>
import numpy as np
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\init.py", line 142, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\init.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\init.py", line 74, in <module>
from numpy.testing import _numpy_tester
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\init.py", line 10, in <module>
from unittest import TestCase
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\init.py", line 64, in <module>
from .main import TestProgram, main
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\unittest\main.py", line 4, in <module>
import argparse
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\argparse.py", line 87, in <module>
import copy as _copy
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Desktop\copy.py", line 7, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>
import matplotlib.colorbar
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
import matplotlib.artist as martist
File "C:\Users\Administartor\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 15, in <module>
from . import cbook, docstring, rcParams
ImportError: cannot import name 'rcParams'
```

Comment: いきなりエラーを貼るより、まず言葉による説明を先に書いた方が読み手に取って親切かなと思いますので次回から参考にしてみてください。

Comment: わかりました！　参考になります

Comment: こちらで既に解決済のようですね。[Anaconda python ファイル　エラー](https://teratail.com/questions/233707)

Answer (score 1):

他のQ&Aサイトの[回答](https://teratail.com/questions/233707#reply-340919)で解決済みのようですので、ほぼ原文のまま転載いたします。(リンクの構文のみ書き換えました)

> 同じ（仮想）環境にcondaとpipでモジュールインストールしてはいけないそうです。
>   異なる管理ツールを使うことにより不具合が生じるようです。下記リンクが詳しいです。
>
> [condaとpip：混ぜるな危険](http://onoz000.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/11/142347)
>
> 今回のエラーが上記に該当するのかは分かりませんが、Anacondaの環境が壊れてしまった可能性はあるかと思います。
>
> 仮想環境であればその環境を削除すれば直るでしょう。baseにcondaとpipを混ぜてしまった場合は残念ですがAnacondaの再インストールでしょうか。